# Django: How to add user(author of the POST request) before save in serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm tried to add author of the request before saving it in **serializers.py**

And got error:

```
Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0000029169C48040>": "Category_product.posted_user" must be a "User" instance.
```

**models.py**

```
class Category_product(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    posted_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

**views.py**

```
class Category_productDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Category_product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Category_productSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class Category_productSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    post_user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='posted_user.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Category_product
        fields = ['id', 'category_name','post_user']
        
        def validate(self, data):
            data['posted_user'] = self.context['request'].user
            return data
```

Comment: I'm not sure that creating it as ReadOnlyField and then trying to override it would work.

Comment: It works, but for superusers

Comment: from running the endpoint or the admin?

Comment: axios POST request, not Admin Panel. (If I understand your question truly)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the user in your view?
Assuming you have Authentacion set up, because if not everyone could get in and it won't be a user, it would be Anonymous User instance.

If that's not the case, you can try it out in the view with perform create:

```py
class Category_productDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Category_product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Category_productSerializer
    
     def get_user(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return user

     def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """
        Set the sender to the logged in user.
        """
        serializer.save(posted_user=self.get_user())
```

Comment: I tried, anyway it sets the default value(default=1), which means function is not changing the user.

Comment: @ShukurSharofiddinov if any request must send a user then why set a default? just remove the default field

Comment: I removed the default value, but now it saves not authorized user but first user

Comment: you need to add authentication and permission classes in order to make sure a user is real